# Method for copying bytes from Channels to Paths and vice versa?

Tags: java, nio

I found there are two methods for copying bytes between `Path`s and `Input/OutputStream`s

```
Files#copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)
Files#copy(Path source, OutputStream out)
```

Are there any methods for using `Readable/WritableByteChannel`s?

Say,

```
copy(ReadableByteChannel in, Path target, CopyOption... options)
copy(Path source, WritableByteChannel out)
```

?

I already know there are handy methods for changing Streams and Channels.

```
Channels#newChannel(InputStream)
Channels#newChannel(OutputStream)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How did you find those two methods? How do you want to use `Readable` and `WritableByteChannel`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want some `copy(Path source, WritableByteChannel out)`

Comment: If you already know about the `Channels.newChannel()` you should also know about the [`Channels.newOutputStream(WriteableByteChannel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)) method, which is all you need.